# QGIS does not export heatmap SLD-files

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, sld, heat-map

At the moment I am creating a webmap with PostGIS and GeoServer. I want to style the data using SLD-files, because my data keeps updating.

I have made SLD-files for Points and Polygons and that worked.

(*I imported the data in QGIS, then styled the data and exported the SLD-file, which I then imported as a style in GeoServer. When I changed the data in the database, then (for example) the color changed of the polygon in the WMS-layer created by GeoServer.)*

Now I did the same with a heatmap. I imported the data in QGIS, made a heatmap and tried to export a SLD-file. Unfortunately, this does not work. The file contains the following sentence:

FeatureRendererV2 heatmapRenderer not implemented yet-->

I cannot use this SLD-file now for GeoServer.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: I also want to use this SLD-files to make isolines

Comment: Sounds like you should make a bug report/feature request (issues.qgis.org). Be sure to search the existing reports to make sure you're not duplicating.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can make it work, or even if it's a QGIS bug.  It sounds like QGIS has a vendor specific option that it can use in SLD or internal style files.  You can export the style (because you might want to import it on another QGIS installation), but you can't use in GeoServer because that only understands standard SLD plus any GeoServer *vendor* specific directives.

Depending on the nature of your data, you might want to consider using MapServer rather than GeoServer because it offers the ability to create both isolines ([contours](https://mapserver.org/input/vector/contour.html)) and heatmaps ([Kernel Density](https://mapserver.org/output/kerneldensity.html#kerneldensity)) as an output for a WMS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think you you are right about the fact that QGIS might not be the right tool to make the SLD's. (But I thought that would work, because it did work for some styling options.) Recently I came across the rendering transformations in GeoServer (https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html) and there they describe the contour and barnes surface interpolation for example. It might be a lot of work to make my own SLD-files, but I don't see why MapServer would be better. Could you maybe explain that?

Comment: (I am using weather data from observation stations.)

Comment: In this example MapServer takes SLD out of the equation, it would natively serve out heatmaps or contours, from your PostGIS database.

Comment: I did not know that. That would obviously be great (also for the performance probably). But that is not possible with GeoServer? Because GeoServer is running great now (apart from the styling) and it gives me the opportunity to make WMS layers that I want to combine in my own build application later.

Comment: AFAIK GeoServer doesn't have that capability, both MapServer and GeoServer provide standards compliant WMS so it should be a problem for your web application.  and of course there's nothing stopping you having a client that uses WMS from multiple sources.